# Need to setenv in htaccess if uri is to root

Tags: .htaccess

I am using .htaccess to create cache-control headers on the basis of URI extension (Lightspeed Webserver v5.4)

```
DirectoryIndex index.htm
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
SetEnv Request_URI \.(htm|html|php|xml) HTM Header set Cache-Control "no-cache" env=HTM
```

This works fine for all the designated file extensions. Also works fine if the Default Page is specified (example.com/index.htm). It DOES NOT WORK when the URI is to the root of the domain (example.com/).

Tried to set the env variable by detecting the Request_URI of /

```
SetEnv Request_URI ^/$ HTM
```

Tried to explicitly rewrite the request to index.htm

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain\.com/index.htm [L]
```

Still not working...?

Comment: what kind of error message or status code do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. Instead of getting Cache-Control "no-cache" header, I get the default Cache-Control header for the server: Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/$ HTM instead of SetEnv Request_URI ^/$ HTM. SetEnv examines the URL after any RewriteRules, whereas SetEnvIf examines before rewrites. I had RewriteRules in the htaccess that prevented SetEnv from determining the request was for the root.   [See Apache docs](http://apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv).